# NULLIF returns first character of existing value instead of entire value

Tags: sql, sql-server

As I understand, in the query below, the value of an existing column should remain if the first value in `NULLIF` is an empty string. In my actual query, those are variables, but I have placed actual values in the query to make it shorter.

`ISNULL(NULLIF(N'', N''), Pwd) => ISNULL(NULL, Pwd) => Pwd`

Instead, what is happening is the first character is being set as the value. Run query below and keep an eye on the value of Pwd.

```
DECLARE @tblHello TABLE (
    UserID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    FirstName VARCHAR(50),
    LastName VARCHAR(50),
    CompanyName VARCHAR(80),
    Pwd VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,  
    Email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    CreatedDate DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT SYSUTCDATETIME(),
    LastUpdated DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT SYSUTCDATETIME(), 
    isActive BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT(1)
)

INSERT INTO @tblHello (FirstName, LastName, CompanyName, Pwd, Email)
VALUES ('First', 'Last', 'Testing this', 'This is the password', 'test@email.com')

UPDATE @tblHello
SET
    Email = ISNULL(NULLIF(N'testuser58@email.com', ''), Email),
    FirstName = ISNULL(NULLIF(N'Updated', ''), FirstName),
    Pwd = ISNULL(NULLIF(N'', N''), Pwd),
    LastName = ISNULL(NULLIF(N'YmFaADIDaQVauHF', ''), LastName),
    isActive = ISNULL(NULLIF(1, ''), isActive),
    CompanyName = ISNULL(NULLIF(N'Testing Co', ''), CompanyName)
WHERE UserID = 1

SELECT *
FROM @tblHello
```

I get the following result for Pwd: (rest of columns ommitted)

```
Pwd CompanyName Email
T   Testing Co  testuser58@email.com
```

This happens with or without the pre-pended 'N'. Why is this happening?

Comment: `isnull` takes its type from the first parameter, which in your case is an empty string i.e. `varchar(1)`. Try `isnull(NULLIF(N'    ', N''),'test')` for comparison. Change `isnull` to `coalesce` to fix.

Comment: @DaleBurrell Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ISNULL()` converts the replacement value to the type of the check expression. In your case it is defaulting to `CHAR(1)`.

According to **MSDN**

> The value of check_expression is returned if it is not NULL;
>   otherwise, replacement_value is returned after it is implicitly
>   converted to the type of check_expression, if the types are different.
>   replacement_value can be truncated if replacement_value is longer than
>   check_expression.

[**ISNULL (Transact-SQL)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

You should use `COALESCE()` instead of `ISNULL()` to avoid any truncation.

Answer (score 2):

Its just the problem of datatype. You are using

```
ISNULL(NULLIF(N'', N''), 'Ravi')
```

here `N''` having the length of 1 so just cast the `N''` to the desired `nvarchar` length you will get the correct output

Try

```
ISNULL(NULLIF(cast(N'' as nvarchar(max)), N''), 'Ravi')
```

Comment: This works as well, but it's more work than simply using `COALESCE()`.

Answer (score 1):

I replaced your codeline with the below one, it works

```
 Pwd = ISNULL(CAST(NULLIF(N'', N'') AS varchar(50)), Pwd),
```

It should be happening because of the datatype that return by the NULLIF() Function. Anyway thank you for the question, found something new.

Comment: This works as well, but it's more work than simply using `COALESCE()`.